# jQuery AJAX .each() count items

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, html

I'm pulling data from an XML DB. It's roughly:

```
<record>
  <eventname></eventname>
  <company></company>
  <city></city>
  <state></state>
</record>
```

I then parse it with the following:

```
success: function(xml){
$('record',xml).each(function() {
    var evname = $(this).find('eventname').text();
    var co = $(this).find('company').text();
    var city = $(this).find('city').text();
    var state = $(this).find('state').text();
    ...
```

After I have the variables, I run an each() for the individual states:

```
$(this).find('state').each(function(){
```

This way I can return events for each state, and it's working great. What I need to do this year, however, is provide a count of events in each state. For various reasons, the most reliable item is "city". So I tried:

```
var count = $(this).find('city').length;
```

But when I parse it with this in the state loop:

```
$('<div></div>').html('<p>Total: '+ count +'</p>').prependTo('.'+ state);
```

I get a paragraph line for each city and the resulting number of "1", so:

> Total: 1 Total: 1 Total: 1

...

I think that's because AJAX is looping through each record and just returning a single result when it finds it. The count (number of paragraphs) is correct on in each state. If a state has 15 events, there are 15 "Total: 1"s prepended. So the question I have (and I've tried a lot of different methods of parsing), is how do I sum the numbers and get a result like: "Total: 15"?

Comment: can you provide your `state` loop, and where/when it is called?

Comment: It's there in my post. It's called on $(document).ready, and after $('record',xml).each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it! Turns out I was heading down the wrong path by looking at a sibling, when I needed to just focus on the record.

My colleague wrote a function:

```
var recordsList = [];
var statesObj = {};

function parser() {
    recordsList.forEach(function(record) {
        if( !statesObj[record.state] ) {
            // If state key doesn't exist, create it
            // Each state will have its own key for each indexing, along with a records list
            statesObj[record.state] = {
                records: [record],
                dot_on_map: false
            }
        }
        else {
            // If state key exists, Then just add to it.
            // The records list in the state key should exist during this iteration
            statesObj[record.state].records.push(record);
        }
    })

    //console.log("records:", recordsList);
    //console.log("states:", statesObj);
    render();
}

function render() {
    Object.keys(statesObj).forEach(function(key) {
        let state = key;
        let stateObj = statesObj[key]; ...
```

From there, it was just: `$('<div></div>').html('<p>Total: '+ stateObj.records.length +'</p>').prependTo('.'+ state);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
success: function (xml) {
    var count = 0;
    $('record', xml).each(function () {
        ...
        count++;
        ...
```

I noticed that `find('city')` always returns 1. So increasing `count` with 1 in each iteration should work.

Comment: Nope. count++ just increases it to Total: 2, Total: 2, Total: 2... Still puts in the same number of cities, so it didn't double the results, just the printed number.

Comment: Let's see if I understand correctly. So you want to count the events in each state and you're doing that by counting the different cities in each state? Because each city can only have 1 event?